# using pandas how do I get the mean of last two rows in a group

Tags: python, pandas

The code mentioned below seems to work.
Calling `tail` function on a sorted group is able to give me the last n rows of a group.
Is this the documented behaviour of the tail function for a group.The pandas documentation does not mentioned it and I am worried that in the next version this behaviour may change.
Also is there some other way to do the following. Using the `apply` function seems to be very slow for large dataset.
The pandas version used in 0.7.3

```
df1=pds.DataFrame({'A' : ['CU','CU','CU','CU','CU','AU','AU','AU','AU','AU'],'B':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]}).sort(['A']).reset_index().drop(['index'],axis=1)
df2=df1.groupby(['A'])
df3=df2.tail(2).groupby(['A'])
df3.mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation [does mention head/tail](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/basics.html#head-and-tail).

And for your code, use `pivot_table`:

```
a = pds.DataFrame({'A' : ['CU','CU','CU','CU','CU','AU','AU','AU','AU','AU'],
                   'B':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]}).sort(['A'])

a.pivot_table(rows='A', values='B', aggfunc=lambda x: x.tail(2).mean())
```

returns

```
AU    4.5
CU    4.5
```

Comment: The documentation is only for using tail for a Series or DataFrame and does not mention if tail function when applied to each group returns the last n rows of each group

Comment: I think the key here is to get the hang of the "split-apply-combine" paradigm-- doing something group-by-group is the same as writing a function to do that operation on the whole DataFrame, then using it with GroupBy.apply or pivot_table as @eumiro has shown